# Total confusion about line endings

Tags: git

I'm on Windows. I have set my `core.eol` to `native`. I have set my `core.autocrlf` to `false`. I'm pretty sure I started out with files containing CRLF line endings, all of them being one of `.clj`, `.md`, or `.gitignore`. I committed them. Then in the next commit I committed the following `.gitattributes`

```
* text=auto

*.bat text
*.bib text
*.clj text
*.java text
*.md text
*.tex text
*.txt text

*.jpg binary
*.pdf binary
*.png binary
```

In that commit, the diff said every line of every file changed (the line endings I assume).

Having set `core.eol` to `native`, I thought I would get CRLF in my working tree, but that is not the case (only for the `.gitattributes` file, no other file, including `.gitignore`). I didn't notice earlier because I'm using Vim.

I thought the diff for the gitattributes commit looked ugly, so I tried setting different values for `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol`, for example setting them to `true` and `crlf` respectively, and doing `git filter-branch --tree-filter HEAD`. I got the error `error: core.autocrlf=input conflicts with core.eol=crlf`. I checked with `git config --get core.autocrlf` and that returned `true`. So why do I get the error?

I'm very confused. What I want is CRLF line endings in my working tree, and commits that don't change my line endings, i.e. they are LF when committed right from the start, and stay that way. How can I achieve that?

Comment: maybe this? https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: @akonsu yeah I've read that, but why do I get the error `core.autocrlf=input conflicts with core.eol=crlf`?

Comment: @StevenPenny No reason, I just picked one. But still, some consistency would be nice. And sometimes files might be CRLF from the beginning on Windows, and that should not mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

I am also on Windows. I use Git. My editor of choice is
[Notepad2](http://xhmikosr.github.io/notepad2-mod)

With this setup I have changed default line endings in Notepad2 to `LF`. As you
[can see](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig)
I did not have to change Git EOL settings.

Now both locally and remotely my files use `LF` which feels simple and right.

Comment: What happens if someone else, also on Windows, comes along and commits CRLF endings?

Comment: @oskarkv if they do that is an error, to be fixed with `git revert`

Answer (score 1):

This very first line of your `.gitattributes` file:

```
* text=auto
```

basically ignores your setting for `core.autocrlf` and turns on line ending conversion for all users of your repository, including yourself.

If you don't want automatic line ending conversion, then you shouldn't use that setting in the `.gitattributes` file.

See [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) and [gitattributes Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for more details.

Comment: I want line ending conversion, but I don't want them to change all of a sudden. It's not too bad if it just happen once, when I commit .gitattributes though.

Also, why don't I get CRLF when checking out my files? I have `core.eol=native`, I thought that was going to give me CRLF in my working tree.

Comment: The way automatic line ending conversion works in general, with `* text=auto`, if you're on Windows, then **ALL** text files that have CRLF are converted to LF when committing to the repo, but are still checked out into your working copy with CRLFs.  Any text files that started out with LF in your working copy are committed as-is, but are then checked back out with CRLF instead.  If you want specific files to still be checked out as LF instead, you'll need to specify that in the `.gitattributes` below `* text=auto`, for example `*.sh text eol=lf` makes all shell scripts LF on checkout.